# Removing multiple seasonalities from time series

Tags: time-series, python, seasonality, statsmodels, multiple-seasonalities

I'm using `statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose` to remove seasonality from a time series. I can remove a seasonal component in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
# giving me a dataframe of columns ds and y, ds being a timestamp and y the signal

signal = df.y - seasonal_decompose(df.y, freq=7).seasonal
```

That makes signal the raw data with weekly seasonality removed.

What I want to do is remove all 4 seasonal components (weekly, monthly, quarterly, yearly) in this way, but I'm not sure whether to do it in the order of largest period to smallest or vice versa. For example I might do:

```
w = seasonal_decompose(df.y, freq=7)
r = df.y - w.seasonal
m = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=30)
r = r - m.seasonal
q = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=91)
r = r - q.seasonal
y = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=365)
r = r - y.seasonal
```

or, the reverse:

```
y = seasonal_decompose(df.y, freq=365)
r = df.y - w.seasonal
q = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=91)
r = r - m.seasonal
m = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=30)
r = r - q.seasonal
w = seasonal_decompose(r, freq=7)
r = r - y.seasonal
```

Which is preferable, and ideally why?

Answer (score 2):

do it simulataneously with a SARMAX model https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf where you disallow identification of the pulses, level shifts, local time trends and ARIMA structure

Daily data is often sufficiently handled with day-of-the-week and monthly indicators. If the data is based upon human habits then we often get day-of-the-month , lead and lag effects around holidays , day-of-the-month wt al.

Annual effects if the exist can be usually handled with level shifts or deterministic time trends .Seldom do we see quarterly effects being needed if monthly effects are in place.